# Why not selection text replaced by special character and how to remove this special character?

Tags: javascript, dom, range, rangy

I want to this type of demo;
Simple String to here : "This is a demo text."

selection text : "demo"

Click button replace by special character => |^selectedText^|

ReplacedText : |^demo^|

removing special character when click on replace button and checking before special character added or not.

After get Original text : demo

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/varsadadj/UnwsL/)

```
var regexp = new RegExp(sel, "gi");
var str = blankStr;
var pattern = str.match(regexp, sel);
var replaceStr = "|^" +sel+ "^|";
document.getElementById('editable1').innerHTML = blankStr.replace(sel,replaceStr);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What special character are you talking about?

Comment: In your question you say `^`, but the Javascript has `*`.

Comment: Sorry,It's remove it and change code please recheck it.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question. What special character do you want to remove, and what problem are you having removing it?

Comment: because i am making fill in the blanks exercise, I am using wysiwyg editor, i put one button in editor toolbar for replace selection text and i want to answer replaced by special character after and before |^Dhaval^|

Comment: That's what happens, isn't it? I select `our`, click the button, and it gets replaced with `|^our^|`.

Comment: Yes, I want to this but here do not remove second time click on this button.and remove special character.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your poor English is just making it harder for me to figure out what you want. Please post a complete example in the question: What the whole original text looks like, what you select, and what the final result should be after you click the button.

Comment: I don't understand that. Please UPDATE THE QUESTION, don't add to the comments.

Comment: Okay please recheck my question, I am edited here!

Comment: So you want the final result to be `|^demo^|` instead of `This is a |^demo^| text.`?

Comment: Yes, I want to same here! Now, Sir You have understand my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/varsadadj/7gcr6/

Answer (score 0):

This seems too easy, I must still be misunderstanding. The entire thing can be replaced with:

```
document.getElementById('editable1') = '|^' + sel + '^|';
```

Comment: But how to remove added this special character when i have mistakely replace to selected text. http://jsfiddle.net/varsadadj/7gcr6/ see also this js fiddle demo but here problem is that before bold completely working replacing. When i replace selected text to after bold any text could not replaced their position.